# How to connect removable disk to an infected PC

Tags: windows, virus, malware, anti-virus, removable-media

What precautions should I take before connecting a removable storage device (like pendrives, External HDD, Memory cards) to an **infected PC** to avoid spreding infection to the removable disk?

There are a lot of threads explaining the precaution/steps to take when connecting an infected removable disk to a clean PC without getting infected, but I could not find any posts explaining the otherway around.
I know that you can use an antivirus/antimalware tool to scan and remove infection from the infected pc or from the removable disk after it got infected. Some times, the first option isn't feasible, the second option might become a pain if the removable drive is very large in capacity and have a large amount of files.
I am looking for answers for Windows PC, but those for other OSs will be considered as a bonus :)

Comment: Disable Autoplay on the infected PCs before connecting, [also apply this patch from Microsoft on the pc you made the usb drive with, then format and remake drive. .](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3071756)

Comment: Why not just... boot from a live linux and copy the files there since the windows virus won't run anyway. Or setup a FTP server in the pc and get the files from there

Answer (score 3):

If you know a PC is infected, but don't know how the malware operates that has infected it, you need to assume the removable media will also become infected once you attach it to the infected PC, unless you can write-protect the media. Some malware will confine itself to just the boot partition of a system. Other malware will look for removable media to infect, since removable media provide the malware with a mechanism to spread the infection to other systems.  One quite famous example of malware that used USB flash drives to spread is [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet), which appears to have been targeted to infect Iranian nuclear facilities, but there are plenty of less famous ones as well designed to spread among personal and business PCs by people moving such media from system to system.

E.g., from the Wikipedia article [USB flash drive security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive_security):

> The prevalence of malware infection by means of USB flash drive was
>   documented in a 2011 Microsoft study analyzing data from more than 600
>   million systems worldwide in the first half of 2011. The study found
>   that 26 percent of all malware infections of Windows system were due
>   to USB flash drives exploiting the AutoRun feature in Microsoft
>   Windows. That finding was in line with other statistics, such as the
>   monthly reporting of most commonly detected malware by antivirus
>   company ESET, which lists abuse of autorun.inf as first among the top
>   ten threats in 2011.

You could boot the infected PC from a [live CD/DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), so that the malware on the infected system does not get an opportunity to run, then transfer the files you need to a removable drive or over the network. You should not attach the removable media while booted into the operating system on the system's hard drive, however. Attach it only when booted into the operating system on the live CD/DVD or when the system is powered off and you are certain it will boot from the CD or DVD when you power it on. But, if you don't know how the malware on the infected system operates, you need to be concerned that files you transferred may be infected. Malware can infect .doc, .exe, .pdf and many other types of files, even some types of image files, so you would need to scan any files transferred afterwards.

Comment: Better yet: Download and Run one of these on the computer - https://www.google.se/search?&q=f-secure+rescue+cd

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple: only a SD card with a hardware write-protection switch, connected through a USB card reader, will be safe. All other devices such as harddisk are at risk to be infected of erased since the virus can remove any write protection on file system.

Comment: Using write protect mode restrict the purpose of connecting it to another pc (not all the time) if we want to copy some files to the removable disk.

Comment: @RogUE, then you should assume that you've infected the removable drive by attaching it to an infected PC. You could disable Windows autorun feature on another system to which you might connect it, but unless you can disinfect the removable media afterwards, including all files on it, if you connect it to another PC, assume that you may also infect that PC, especially if the removable media has lots of other files, e.g., .exe, .doc, .xls, .pdf that malware could infect. If it has infected other files, just turning off autorun on PCs you might connect the drive to isn't sufficient.

Comment: The little switch on the side of an SD card is no guarantee whatsoever that the card will remain read-only.